# adding react-bootstrap cards but with image link thats user defined

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

i am new to react and trying to make my first own project . i created one component that will have cardDeck which i exported to other components.after doing this , i was wondering how to make card image, title and text user defined.

this is my cards.js component

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {CardDeck,Card} from 'react-bootstrap';
    
    class cards extends Component{
    
      render(){
        return(   <React.Fragment> < CardDeck>
          <Card>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px160" />
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Card title</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
                additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
              </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
            </Card>
         </CardDeck></React.Fragment>
    );
      }
    
    }
    export default cards;
```

this is the component in which i am using the card.js component

```
import React from 'react';

import Cards from '../bootstrap/Cards';
 
class home extends React.Component {
 
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment> <Cards/>
            <Cards/><Cards/><Cards/></React.Fragment>
           
          
        );
    }
}

export default home;
```

also , if you guys could help me with keeping number of cards user defined as you can see i am trying to add  multiple times .

this is also my first question here so i am sorry if its not how it should be done .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working example of what you would like to do using create-react-app without bootstrap

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cards: [],
    title: '',
    text: '',
  };

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      cards: [
        ...this.state.cards,
        { title: this.state.title, text: this.state.text },
      ],
      title: '',
      text: '',
    });
  };

  changeTitle = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      title: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  changeText = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      text: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder=""
            name="title"
            value={this.state.title}
            onChange={this.changeTitle}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder=""
            name="text"
            value={this.state.text}
            onChange={this.changeText}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        {this.state.cards.map((card) => {
          return <Card key={card.title} title={card.title} text={card.text} />;
        })}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      <p>{props.text}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

There is a lot going on in this question so I'll try to break it all down.

To dynamically render a list in React the most common way is to map over an array and return a list of components based on the data in the array. So an empty array is set in our state named `cards` which will represent the cards a user has made.

We can render items in that array here:

```
{this.state.cards.map((card) => {
   return <Card key={card.title} title={card.title} text={card.text} />;
})}
```

Notice how the `title` and `text` are being passed in as props to the `Card` component

We then need a way for a user to add a card with a title and text. The easiest way to do that is by creating a form with two inputs. We set `title` and `text` to empty strings in state and set the changes made in the two form inputs to state using `changeTitle` and `changeText` event handlers. Those functions are similar and can refactored into one function, but I wanted to make the code simple and easy to understand.

Once we are able to track the changes made to the form we need a way to submit the title and text so a user can create a new card. The `onSubmit` handles that. The values of `this.state.cards` is spread onto `cards` in `this.setState` with a new element added with the current state of the `text` and `title`. `text` and `title` are then set to an empty string so a user doesn't see their previous input.

This fundamental React that you will likely be doing a lot in a React applications. I strongly recommend reviewing and understanding the code as much as possible and asking/looking up answers to any questions you may have about how the code works. Also, hooks are more common these days so I recommend learning how to do this using hooks as well